# Here API Weather Icon

Tags: javascript, json, api, here-api, weather-api

Working on a weather app and couldn't find any weather icons from HERE.

In the Json response there is this:

```
icon: "5"
iconLink: "https://weather.ls.hereapi.com/static/weather/icon/4.png"
iconName: "high_clouds"
```

But the iconLink doesn't work, it shows unauthorized.

In the [documentations](https://developer.here.com/documentation/destination-weather/dev_guide/topics/example-weather-observation.html), the link in the Json response works but it's a different one that the API provides.

And I can't find anything that can be helpful with that regards.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to add the API token at the end of the URL similar to this:
`https://weather.ls.hereapi.com/static/weather/icon/4.png?apiKey={APIKEY}`